# Unexpected behavior when working with PhysicsBodies in SpriteKit

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

I´ve got some issues with the physics bodies in this exercise.

when the dot(snake) is moving very fast, it "squeezes" itself through the physics bodies of the bricks. Can someone help, please?

[image]

snake:

```
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = snakeCategory;
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = lineCategory | brickCollissionCategory;
self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = brickContactCategory;
self.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
self.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
self.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
self.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
```

bricks:

```
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = brickCollissionCategory;
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = snakeCategory;
self.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
self.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
self.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
```

Comment: Is it going to fast for the physics bodies to detect collisions?

Comment: i don't know. it moves as fast as you swipe on the screen (x only).

Comment: I'm new to `SpriteKit`, so I'm not too sure what the problem is. However, I do know that you do not need to set `self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity` if you set the `physicsBody` to not be dynamic.

Comment: But your saying that the "snake" will stop if you hit the bricks directly?

Comment: actually yes (in this case). otherwise when the snake touches the bricks, the bricks get pushed by the dot. i want them to be static.

Comment: Yes, it should be dynamic, but that also means that the brick won't be affected by any physics in the scene. That is why you do not need to set the gravity property, however, you should keep other properties such as restitution.

Comment: How are you moving the dot? Are you applying a force or impulse?

Comment: @George_E - as 0x141E implies, if you are directly setting the position of the dot, rather than applying a force or impulse to it, then this could happen. It could also happen if the bricks are moving slightly from the collision, creating a gap the snake could move through. This can be mitigated by disabling collisions between the bricks and the snake, so that the bricks do not move.

Comment: at first i moved the dot directly but then i´ve changed it to a SKAction(move). still the same problem :(

Comment: that is your problem then, you are using SKAction move, and that action is going to keep going until it reaches it's destination.  The more you hold it back,  the higher the "jump" is going to be to account for missing time

Comment: no i have an array with locations. it contains only the last two locations which are added in the touchesMoved method. with this two location i calculate the difference between them and then i add the difference to the snakes position via action like: snake.position = CGPointMake(snake.position.x + diffX, snake.position.y). i will try this with applying an impulse.